# Is it possible to create an IIS web farm using WFF and ARR using a single server?

Tags: iis, asp.net, web-farm

I'm developing a web application that will be deployed in a web farm environment on IIS 7.5.

Currently I don't have multiple servers to test my application. Is there a way to create and test a web farm on a single machine?

Answer (score 0):

You could use VMware or Microsofts Hyper-V server to virtualize your farm.

If your server is fast enough and has enough memory you even could get acceptable speeds, at least for developing.